# read a div from an html file to a javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read the colTwo div from the file members.html (in the same folder) into a variable, then set innerHTML to that variable. The result is 'undefined'. How can I fix this?

```
var fredpagevar;
 $.get("members.html", function(data){
     fredpagevar = $(data).find('#colTwo').html();
 });
function fredpage(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = fredpagevar;}
```

Answer (score 1):

based on your markup :  `<li><a href="#" onclick='fredpage()'>Fred</a></li>`

Try this -

```
function fredpage(){
   $.get("members.html", function(data){
     $('#boldStuff').html($(data).find('#colTwo').html());
   }); 
}
```

Comment: I guess , You are calling `fredpage()` from somewhere else ?

Comment: and `$.get` is called on page load ?

Comment: I reposted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470681/trying-to-get-jquery-load-to-work

Comment: You should edit this question. Answer for my comment under my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var fredpagevar;
$.get("members.html", function(data){
     fredpagevar = $(data).find('#colTwo').html();
}).done(function (){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = fredpagevar;
});
```

Your function probably fired before `get` method receive data from file.

---

Or second usage (in case when you use your function in other place):

```
var fredpagevar;
$.get("members.html", function(data){
     fredpagevar = $(data).find('#colTwo').html();
}).done(fredpage());

function fredpage(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = fredpagevar;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, this time it doesn't say undefined it just doesn't do anything

Comment: put `console.log(data)` inf first line of get method and check is it empty

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$.get("members.html", function (data) {
    $('#boldStuff').html($(data).find('#colTwo').html());
});
```