# trying to get jquery load to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I navigate through the menu I want only the contentarea div to change and not reload the whole page. I want to use the jquery load function to read a div from another page (from members.html div colTwo) and insert it onto the page (into div contentarea). I have been trying but couldn't get it to work.

Any help editing this script would be helpful!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src ='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function memberspage(){
    $('#contentarea').load('members.html #colTwo');
}
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">

    <div id="colOne">

        <div id="menu1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick='memberspage()'>Members</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-news">
            <h2>Recent Updates</h2>
            <p><strong>None At This Time</strong> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentarea"><h2>Starting Text</h2></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src ='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>` missing `>`...

Comment: thanks - it still doesnt work though

Comment: Guys this man didn't accept any answer on his questions (look on his profile). Also this question is edited version of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469738/read-a-div-from-an-html-file-to-a-javascript-var.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've declared your `memberspage()` function inside a document ready handler, which means that it is not in scope when you try to call it from an inline `onclick` handler on your anchor element - inline attributes like that can only access global functions.

You can fix this by moving the function declaration out of the document ready (making it global), but a better option would be to bind the click handler with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu1 a").click(function(e){
        $('#contentarea').load('members.html #colTwo');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I've added `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour on the anchor click which might otherwise scroll back to the top of the page. (In an inline handler you would get the same effect by returning false.)

Note also that your `<script>` element that includes jquery.js is missing a closing `>` right before the closing `</script>`.

Comment: are you sure ? it really doesnt matter. The problem is with evaluating the URL

Comment: @karthikr - Yes I'm sure. There's no problem with the string specified in `.load()`, it means load from that URL but filter based on the selector.

Comment: ok I replaced the script with what you recomended. I fixed the > typo, what do I do with the a href line?

Comment: If you bind the click handler the way I've shown you'd simply remove the inline `onclick`. The `href` should stay as is. So: `<a href="#">Members</a>`. If it still doesn't work check the browser console for errors, and double check the URL and selector that you pass to `.load()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function on the global scope to use it in attribute-based events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function memberspage(){
    $('#contentarea').load('members.html #colTwo');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

memberspage() has been defined but you aren't CALLING it from anywhere.

Comment: thats not true - It is being called from `<li><a href="#" onclick='memberspage()'>Members</a></li>`

Comment: Sorry I missed that.. too used to unobtrusive javascript :)